# Quartz .NET - remove trigger if all future fire times in past

Tags: quartz.net

I've set up the quartz scheduler to ignore misfires and move on to the next fire time (using *.WithMisfireHandlingInstructionNextWithRemainingCount()* and *.WithMisfireHandlingInstructionDoNothing()*). This works fine but if there is no next fire time the trigger will just keep the old next fire time that has already misfired and wait for it to fire (it will never fire because it is in the past).

The way I'm testing this is pausing a trigger and waiting for the fire times to pass/misfire. The trigger's state is updated to COMPLETE only after resuming and remains in the database. I want the trigger to remove itself from the database (like it normally does when complete). I also want the trigger to complete without me having to resume the trigger but that's a bonus.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the problem was I was setting the start time (using *.StartAt()* method) to the start time of the intervals I was using. For example, let's say it is currently 9am on June 23rd. If I had a trigger that runs daily starting at 3am then the start time of the daily interval is 3am. However, I was also setting the start time of the trigger to 3am, which is in the past. This ended up causing me many issues.